# a11y automation using axe-selenium and java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, accessibility, deque

followed a simple program from the git hub - https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-selenium-java

```
public class CheckAxe {

@Rule
public TestName testName = new TestName();

private WebDriver driver;
private static final URL scriptUrl = CheckAxe.class.getResource("/axe.min.js");

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//Drivers//chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

@Test
public void testAccessibility() {
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");
    JSONObject responseJSON = new AXE.Builder(driver, scriptUrl).analyze();

    JSONArray violations = responseJSON.getJSONArray("violations");

    if (violations.length() == 0) {
        Assert.assertTrue(true, "No violations found");
    } else {
        AXE.writeResults(testName.getMethodName(), responseJSON);
        Assert.assertTrue(false, AXE.report(violations));
    }
}

@AfterClass
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

While execution , get error as below -

> org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Unexpected token '<'
> (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:489)
> at com.deque.axe.AXE.injectIntoFrames(AXE.java:111)
> at com.deque.axe.AXE.inject(AXE.java:74)
> at com.deque.axe.AXE$Builder.execute(AXE.java:368)
> at com.deque.axe.AXE$Builder.analyze(AXE.java:335)
> at utils.CheckAxe.testAccessibility(CheckAxe.java:35)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
> at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
> at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:597)
> at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
> at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
> at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
> at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
> at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
> at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
> at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
> at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Can you please suggest , what I am missing here? My js file is in the below location . sample screenshot -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems Like Chrome Driver executable issues.

It is impossible to run Selenium test scripts on the Google Chrome browser without ChromeDriver executable.

Please download the ChromeDriver exe file form [ChromeExe](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/)

You can keep this file in "C://driver//chromedriver_win32" folder

In your ExampleTest.java class in setup method

```
public void setUp() {
        // ChromeDriver needed to test for Shadow DOM testing support
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",                 
                   "C://driver//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Priya, have used the chrome driver in my script also tried with webdrivermanager as well. But no luck